# How can I send a parameter from the controller to a serializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm very new to Rails. I have the following index function in my controller:

```
def index
  @trip_styles = TripStyle.all
  render json: @trip_styles
end
```

And this is my serializer:

```
class TripStyleSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id,
             :name,
             :trip_style_tag_id,
             :resource,
             :quantity

  def quantity
    for client_tag_quantity in object.marketing_client_tag_quantity
      object = client_tag_quantity.quantity
    end
    return object
  end
end
```

I want to send a new parameter `agent` from my controller to my serializer, but I can't do it. I've tried:

```
@trip_styles.each do |style|
  style[:agent] = @current_agent.id
end
```

And it shows this error: `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError (can't write unknown attribute 'agent')`

Thanks. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: does it work if you add :agent to attributes?  Also what is the error you are getting?

Comment: See my edit @ruby_newbie

Comment: Ok so what happens if you add the :agent attribute to the attributes list?

Comment: @RogerGonzalez when u say want to new param `agent`, i cant understand the question. also why `style[:agent]` ? meanwhile u already serializing it.

Comment: I added an answer because the comments wont allow you to format code

Answer (score 1):

I would say there is a missing relationship in your model, or that the agent_id doesn't belong to your trip style object (and therefore shouldn't be serialized as part of your trip style object). So I think you have a design problem and we would need more information to help properly.

If you want a quick hack, in the controller you could do

#### option 1: adding directly to the serializable hash

```
def index
  @trip_styles = TripStyle.all
  render json: serialize_trip_styles
end

private 
def serialize_trip_styles
  @trip_styles.map { |ts| ts.to_h.merge(agent: @current_agent.id) }
end
```

#### option 2: add an initialization parameter to TripStyleSerializer

```
private 
def serialize_trip_styles
  @trip_styles.map do |ts|
    TripStyleSerializer.new(ts, agent: @current_agent.id)
  end
end
```

You would need to modify the trip style class accordingly with this approach:

```
class TripStyleSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :agent
  def initialize(object, options={})
    @agent = options[:agent]
    super(object, options)
  end
```

Also, as a side note, I advise not to use the variable name `object` in your active model serializers because it clashes with the `object` attribute that you get from inheriting from [ActiveModel::Serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/lib/active_model/serializer.rb)

```
def quantity
  for client_tag_quantity in object.marketing_client_tag_quantity
    # Bad use of object as a variable name
    object = client_tag_quantity.quantity
  end
  return object
  # Btw, this will loop through all the elements and affects the last 
  # item of object.marketing_client_tag_quantity to object
  # which doesn't look like something you want to do
  # If you want to do that though, just 
  # return object.marketing_client_tag_quantity.last.quantity
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you need to add :agent to the attributes list.

```
class TripStyleSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id,
             :name,
             :trip_style_tag_id,
             :resource,
             :quantity,
             :agent

  def quantity
    for client_tag_quantity in object.marketing_client_tag_quantity
      object = client_tag_quantity.quantity
    end
    return object
  end
end
```

Comment: If I add it, it shows this error `NoMethodError (undefined method 'agent' for #<TripStyle:0x007f4a3c8ff740>)`

Comment: Just add an attr_accessor for :agent on your TripStyle class. It should work.